# Unobservable changes

Tags: polymer, dataflow

**test-element.html**

```
house:{ type: String, notify: true}
```

**A.html**

```
<test-element house="my-house"></test-element>
```

**B.html**

```
<test-element house="{{house}}"></test-element>
<div>{{house}}</div>
```

Why `<div>{{house}}</div>` is not `my-house`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom elements are no singletons! Every instance of your Component has its own context. If you want it to behave like a singleton you need to implement [redux](https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux) or use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the information

Answer (score 0):

It's because both the `test-element` are different instantiations. One in `A.html` is not the same element as one in `B.html`, even though they have same definition.

In terms of javascript, you can compare it to declaring calling same function twice:

```
function a(prop1) {
  console.log(prop1);
}

a(1) //logs 1
a() //logs undefined
```

Or if you want to compare it to HTML you can take example of any element (let's say input)

```
<input id="ip1" value="test">
<input id="ip2">
```

Now, if you check value for `ip2` it will not be `test` as it is a new instantiation. Same thing happens for `custom-elements` also.